# How to crawl pages with infinite auto-scroll?

Tags: python, web-crawler, autoscroll

I would like to crawl usernames in a page that has auto next page scrolling (when you scroll down, it shows more results). Let's say I want to get all usernames on [this page](http://www.quora.com/Mathematics/followers). Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you scroll to the end of that page an ajax request is made to a url like:

http://tch578489.tch.quora.com/up/chan3-8882/updates?min_seq=27815516&channel=main-w-dep16-2927332319247211033

You'll want to figure out how it's generating that url and make your requests there, then parse it.

Comment: It is the url where the data comes from for infinite scroll, if your using Chrome check out the network tab in webinspector to see the requests the site is making.

Comment: so if in python I make a urlopen request for that, I will get the next page?

Comment: when I open that I get a message like "({"messages": ["require.enqueue(function(require){require(\"w2.livenode\").reportPageNeedsReload(\"lost_group\")})"], "min_seq": 28309793})"

Comment: It's going to take some work on your part,  you need to see how the site generates those URLs in JavaScript then use that logic in your python to retrieve the list, finally you'll need to figure out how to parse the response.